# Failed to instantiate org.springframework.ai.chat.prompt.Prompt using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I am building an application using `spring-ai` and `spring-data-redis` where I want to store the context of chat in redis as follows

```kotlin
@RedisHash("chatcontexts")
class ChatContextEntity(
    @Id
    val userId: Long,
    var prompt: Prompt,
    var chatType: ChatType // just enum
) : Serializable
```

Serialization and saving to db works however when I try to get the entity from db like `repository.findByid(userId)` I got an error

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.springframework.ai.chat.prompt.Prompt using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
```

I tried to use custom converters like this

```kotlin
@Component
@ReadingConverter
class BytesToAddressConverter : Converter<ByteArray, Prompt> {
    private val serializer: Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Prompt> = Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(ObjectMapper(), Prompt::class.java)

    override fun convert(source: ByteArray): Prompt {
        return serializer.deserialize(source)
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
class ApplicationConfig(
    @Value("\${spring.data.redis.host}") private val host: String,
    @Value("\${spring.data.redis.port}") private val port: Int,
) {

    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): RedisConnectionFactory {
        return LettuceConnectionFactory(host, port)
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisTemplate(connectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory?): RedisTemplate<*, *> {
        val template = RedisTemplate<String, Any>()
        template.connectionFactory = connectionFactory()
        template.keySerializer = StringRedisSerializer()
        template.hashValueSerializer = GenericToStringSerializer(Any::class.java)
        template.valueSerializer = GenericToStringSerializer(Any::class.java)
        return template
    }
}
```

but nothing helps

Comment: try to add lombok annotation @NoArgConstructor or AllArgConstructor  on the classChatContextEntity

Comment: didn't help ://

Comment: can you try by adding all these annotations @AllArgsConstructor +Getter+Builder
+RedisHash

Comment: I solved this by creating my own dtos like a wrappers for those spring boot ai classes